# with sass boostrap default stylings are not getting applied

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-4

I am implementing a nav bar onto my page but then the bootstrap styling doesn't work.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">
 <div class="container-fluid">
<div class="navbar-header">
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
   </div>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  </nav>
```

I m using sass with bootstrap4 but  then the default nav styling don't apply to the page it just displays as simple text.

Do we need to have the following lines?

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link href="scss/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

wherei dont wanna sass i prefer original bootstrap styling thats not working i.e., not getting applied, m using maxcdn to include bootstrap or how do i do it

The bootstrap file to be included into my files or how to I proceed any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to use Bootstrap without actually including Bootstrap, or am I reading that wrong?

Comment: wherei dont wanna sass i prefer original bootstrap styling thats not working i.e., not getting applied, m using maxcdn to include bootstrap or how do i do it